# Notation for summing all elements under the diagonal of a square matrix

Tags: matrices, notation, summation, trace

I have a simple question:

What is the notation for summing all elements under the diagonal of a square matrix?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

If $M=\left[M_{ij}\right]$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, one way to notate the sum of all entries *under* the diagonal is

$\displaystyle \sum_{1\le j<i\le n} M_{ij}$

Another way:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} M_{ij}$

Comment: My understanding is that the term for this set of elements is strict lower triangle.  I've also been looking for such notation (for upper triangle) - David's is best so far that I've found, but nothing wrong with making something up if it hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the diagonal element of a square matrix is its [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29). There are many notations in use for the trace of a matrix $M$, but the ones that I see most frequently are $\text{Tr}(M)$, $\text{tr}(M)$, and sometimes $\text{Sp}(M)$, which is a reference to the German word *Spur* for the same concept. Some will also just write out $\text{Trace}(M)$ or $\text{trace}(M)$, but this is less common in my experience.

Edit: As Christopher Ernst let me know, I may have misunderstood your question. It sounds like you're asking for a notation/word for the sum of the elements of the [subdiagonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subdiagonal.html) of a matrix, and unfortunately I don't believe I have seen a term for it in the literature (or at least one that is widely in use). Hopefully someone can come along with a canonical name/notation for it.

Comment: I thought he wanted the trace too, but his question asks for "the notation $\mathbf{under}$ the diagonal...".   Perhaps he could clarify

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Ah good point. I'll leave my answer here just in case/so that others don't make my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I've never even seen a notation for what he's asking for anyway, but that is how he worded it, so let's wait until he clarifies...

Comment: Sorry, now that I read my entry, I see why it can easily be misunderstood. 

When I say "under the diagonal" I mean not just those immediately below the diagonal, but those below those immediately below, and so on, until and including the left most element at the bottom. 

I think David Peterson gave the correct answer, do people agree?